# My code isn't getting the values I insert into an entry

Tags: python, mysql, sql, tkinter

I've got some code in python using `tkinter` which retrieves the name of a room and uses that to to insert into an SQL database the room name and which site it belongs to. However when I run the code its not retrieving the room name from the entry box.

Can anyone help?

```py
def addroom():
    global screen14
    global roomsinsite
    roomsinsite = StringVar()
    screen14 = Tk()
    screen14.geometry("300x250")
    screen14.title("Insert rooms")
    Label(screen14, text = "Insert room name:", bg = "LightSkyBlue1", width = "300", height = "2").pack()
    Label(screen14, text = "").pack()
    roomsinsite_entry = Entry(screen14, textvariable = roomsinsite)
    roomsinsite_entry.pack()
    Button(screen14, text = "Register room", width = "12", height = "1", command = insertroom).pack()

 

def insertroom():
    sitename4_info = sitename2.get()
    print(sitename4_info)
    roomname1_info = roomsinsite.get()
    print(roomname1_info)
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    # SQL to select the siteID and insert rooms for that paticular site.
    siteID_fetch3 = "SELECT siteID FROM Sites WHERE siteName = %s"
    cursor.execute(siteID_fetch3, [sitename4_info])
    siteID_fetch3 = cursor.fetchall()
    # print out the values retrieved
    print(siteID_fetch3[0][0])
    insertRooms = "INSERT INTO `rooms`(`siteID_fk2`, `roomname`) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    insertRooms_val = (siteID_fetch3[0][0], roomname1_info)
    cursor.execute(insertRooms, insertRooms_val)
    # print out the rows inserted.
    print(cursor.rowcount)
    cnn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having more than one `Tk` in your code, which means your `StringVar` does not know which `Tk` to belong to. So here there are three possible solutions:

- Avoid using more than one `Tk` and replace all child windows with `Toplevel`, so:

```py
screen14 = Toplevel()
roomsinsite = StringVar()
```

- If you are adamant that you want to use more than one instance of `Tk` then you can specify `master` for each `StringVar`, like:

```py
screen14 = Tk()
roomsinsite = StringVar(master=screen14)
```

- To be honest, I wouldn't use `StringVar` with entry widgets except when I want to use `trace`, here if the only purpose of using `StringVar` is for getting the value of the entry widget, then remove it and use `get()` method of the entry widget, like:

```py
roomname1_info = roomsinsite_entry.get()
```

The combination of first and third method seems like best practice, if you ask me. Also here, even if you are not using more than one `Tk`, one of the above methods would certainly solve the problem(as far as something is inputted inside the entry and then the `insertroom()` is called).

Comment: Thank you, makes everything much more easier as I've been having the same issue with other sections of code. Thank you!